# VS error on aspx file Eval(), expecting semi-colon

Tags: c#, asp.net, itemtemplate

I am suddenly getting a CS1002 error on an aspx page when it was working fine. The code:

```
    <asp:DataList ID="StdColorGrid" runat="server"
        EnableViewState="false"
        AllowSorting="true"
        RepeatColumns="5"
        RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
        RepeatLayout="Table">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <div class="swatchBox" >
        <%#Eval("SwatchName") %><br />
        <%#Eval("RGB") %>
    </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

The compiler expects a semicolon on the <%#Eval("RGB")%> line, but no documentation I find specifies a semicolon when using Eval(). Any ideas? If I remove this line, it just reports the same error on the preceeding line.

Comment: *"it just reports the same error on the preceeding line"* - That usually means that you have a problem much earlier in the file.

Comment: As noted, the markup you have looks fine, and if you create a brand new test page, and paste in your markup, it works just fine. This suggests as comment above notes that some other markup is messed up on that page.